# Probability questions in involving combinatorics

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Original question: In your class at school there are 7 students of the 20 that wear glasses. If a group
of 5 students is selected at random to be part of "Recycling committee", what is the probability that all 
will be wearing glasses?

Work:

P(All 5 in the committee are wearing glasses) = # of events when this is true/total # of events

Total # of events = $\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}$ = $\frac{20!}{5!(20-5)!}$

I cannot seem to deduce the # of events when this is true.

Is it simply $\frac{7}{20}$?

Comment: No, it's true when all $5$ of the students of the committee are picked from the $7$ that wear glasses, i.e. it is $7 \choose 5$

Answer (score 1):

The total number of $5$-person committees you can choose would be $\binom{20}{5}=\frac{20!}{5!15!}$. The total number of "all-glasses" committees would be the same idea, but working only with the pool of glasses-wearers. Thus, the numerator of your probability fraction should be $\binom75=\frac{7!}{5!2!}$.

Answer (score 1):

This is a special case of the hypergeometric distribution. There are $\binom{20}{5}$ groups of five people each having the same probability of being chosen. Of these groups, $\binom{7}{5}\binom{13}{0}$ groups  have  all $5$ people wearing glasses (the five people who wear glasses must be chosen among the seven in the class who wear glasses). Thus the probability is
$$
\frac{\dbinom{7}{5}}{\dbinom{20}{5}}
$$

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:**

The number of ways to choose $5$ out of those $7$ students wear classes: $\dfrac{7!}{5!2!}=21$ ways.

The number of ways to choose $5$ out of all $20$ students: $\dfrac{20!}{5!15!}=15504$ ways, is this enough?